# Salesforce - System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001

Tags: apex, trigger

I am getting, System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001 error in trigger. If I run each query independently, the sum of total row is below 50,000. I am not sure what is causing the issue. Attaching trigger.

```
    trigger UpdateProductLineWithTracking on CommercientSF__ArInvoice__c (after insert, after update) {
List<CommercientSF__ArInvoice__c> inv = Trigger.New;

    Map<id, CommercientSF__SorMasterRep__c> MasMap = new Map<id, CommercientSF__SorMasterRep__c>
        ([select id, name, CommercientSF__SalesOrder__c ,
          (select id, name ,CommercientSF__StockCode__c,CommercientSF__SorMasterRep__r.CommercientSF5__Opportunity__c
          from CommercientSF__SorDetailReps__r where CommercientSF__ShipQty__c > 0 and 
          CommercientSF__SorMasterRep__r.CommercientSF5__Opportunity__c != null)
          from CommercientSF__SorMasterRep__c where CommercientSF5__Opportunity__c != null ]);
    system.debug('record count MASMAP ' + MasMap.size());

    Map<id, CommercientSF__SorDetailRep__c> DetMap = new Map<id, CommercientSF__SorDetailRep__c>
    ([select id, CommercientSF__StockCode__c,CommercientSF__SorMasterRep__r.CommercientSF5__Opportunity__c from
    CommercientSF__SorDetailRep__c where CommercientSF__SorMasterRep__r.CommercientSF5__Opportunity__c != null 
    and CommercientSF__ShipQty__c > 0 ]);
    system.debug('record count DETMAP ' + DetMap.size());

    Map<id, Opportunity> OppMap = new Map<id, Opportunity>([
    select id,name,CommercientSF5__Commercient_Sales_Order__c,(select id, productcode, OpportunityId
 from OpportunityLineItems where Opportunity.CommercientSF5__Commercient_Sales_Order__c != null)
    from Opportunity where
    CommercientSF5__Commercient_Sales_Order__c != null]);
    system.debug('record count OPPMAP ' + OppMap.size());

    List<OpportunityLineItem> OLItems = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    for(CommercientSF__ArInvoice__c s : inv)
    {
        CommercientSF__SorMasterRep__c mas = MasMap.get(s.CommercientSF__SorMasterRep__c);

        system.debug('MAS ID ');

        if(mas != null)
        {    
            system.debug('MAS ID : ' + mas.id);
            List<CommercientSF__SorDetailRep__c> DetList = mas.CommercientSF__SorDetailReps__r;

            system.debug('DETAIL LIST');
            if(DetList != null)
            {    
                system.debug('DETAIL LIST SIZE : ' + DetList.size());
                for(Integer j=0; j < DetList.size(); j++)
                {
                    CommercientSF__SorDetailRep__c detail = DetMap.get(DetList[j].id);

                    if(detail != null)
                    {
                        String OppId = detail.CommercientSF__SorMasterRep__r.CommercientSF5__Opportunity__c;
                        String StockCode = detail.CommercientSF__StockCode__c;
                        String Carrier = s.carrier__c;
                        String TrackingInfo = s.TrackingInfo__c;

                        Opportunity Opp = OppMap.get(OppId);

                        if(Opp != null)
                        {
                            List<OpportunityLineItem> OppLines = Opp.OpportunityLineItems;
                            for(Integer i=0; i<OppLines.size(); i++)
                            {
                                if(OppLines[i].ProductCode == StockCode && OppLines[i].OpportunityId == OppID)
                                {
                                    OppLines[i].carrier__c = Carrier; //subject to change
                                    OppLines[i].TrackingInfo__c = TrackingInfo; //subject to change
                                    OLItems.add(OppLines[i]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(OLItems.size() > 0)
    {
        Set<sobject> myset = new Set<sobject>();
        List<sobject> result = new List<sobject>();
        for (sobject s : OLItems) 
        {
            if (myset.add(s)) 
                result.add(s);
        }
        if(result.size() > 0)
            update result;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you sum MasMap.size(), DetMap.size() and OppMap.size() it will be more than 50,000. According to your description. What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

The 50000 Rows limits for a transaction not for individual query. So you need to use Limit to restrict your query. In a single transaction means where your trigger fired or if due to current record any other record get inserted or updated then there Triggers and SOQL will also count in this limit.

You can take help from Limit class to find the Limit

`Limits.getQueryRows()` will return the number of records you already get from query and `Limits.getLimitQueryRows()` to get maximum number of records can be query.

[Reference Limits Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm)